# Is there any way to work in the Futures market with the kucoin or binance API

Tags: api, bots, kucoin

I am making a bot with python that works with the Kucoin api, but I would like to make orders with leverage and for this I need to access futures, but for now I have not found any library or any end point in the Kucoin api that let me access that market,
Do you know of any library for this or it simply cannot be done? Thank you very much in advance

I have been working with the official kucoin api

https://docs.kucoin.com/

Answer (score 0):

there's separate API for Kucoin futures (https://docs.kucoin.com/futures/) and separate library operating on this API (kucoin-futures-python)